# Вызов компонента ReactJS в методе объекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пишу приложение в связке React & react-shepherd. Как вызвать компонент `<Heandler />` в методе объекта, который в свою очередь является шагом в react-shepherd?

```
import logo from './img/logo.png';
import React from 'react';
import Heandler from './Heandler';

const steps = [
    {
        id: 'intro',
        screen: 'dashboard',
        text: '<img src="' + logo + '" alt="logo"><h3>Welcome to TOUR</h3><div>Пройдите небольшой Product tour, чтобы познакомиться с интерфейсом Product</div>',
        classes: 'tour-intro',
        scrollTo: false,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Начать тур',
                type: 'next'
            },
            {
                text: 'Скрыть',
                type: 'hide'
            },
        ],
        when: {
            hide(){
                console.log('henl');
                return <Heandler />
            }
        }
    },
    {...}
]
```

```
import {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Context} from '../../context';

export default function Heandler(){
    const {changeStepScreen} = useContext(Context);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('heandler');
    }, [])


    return null;

}
```